# Removing every other tick on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the graph I am currently generating with the associated code:

[image]

```
values = [2240, 1990, 1460, 1600, 1440, 2240, 100, 5840]
values_count = [0] * 23

#there is a for loop with "if" statements counting up the
# data that lies within 2 bounds - left code out to minimize.

x_axis = np.arange(-250, 5251, 250)
barlist = plt.bar(x_axis, values_count, edgecolor = 'green', align = 'center', width = 290, zorder = 2)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.grid(linestyle = '--', linewidth = 1, alpha = 0.2, zorder = -1)
plt.xticks(x_axis , ['', '0', '', '500', '', '1000', '', '1500', '', '2000', '', '2500', 
'', '3000', '', '3500', '', '4000', '', '4500', '', '5000'])
plt.show()
```

**What the code is supposed to do:**

It reads in a list of values, then determines where the values lie (i.e. between 1500 and 2000), then adds one to `values_count` in the appropriate index. Then it plots a bar chart showing the number of values that lie between 2 values. The code does this, but the issue lies within the x-axis ticks.

**The Issue:**

There are ticks that are located under the bar directly (i.e. below 0, between 0 and 500, 500 and 1000, and so on - best example is from 1000 to 2500). These ticks I'd like to remove while keeping the ticks between the bars (i.e. the ticks that are labeled 0, 500, 1000, and so on). For clarity, I have circled the ticks that should be removed:

[image]

**What I Have Tried:**

`plt.xticks(x_axis)`: this labels the x-axis from -250 to 5250, which provides an overlap of the labels. By adding in the list (`['', 0, '', '500', ..., '', '5000', '']`) as the second argument, it eliminates every other label, making the graph's x-axis clean as such above.

`plticker.MultipleLocator()`: this did not solve my issue of the tick marks being removed, but rather less added more when I inputted a value for this.

`plticker.FixedLocator()`: this did absolutely nothing even after messing with it.

Comment: What happens if you use `plt.xticks(strengths)`? What's wrong with the output you'd get then? Can you please provide a [mcve] and clearly explain how would like it to look like instead?

Comment: If I use that, I would get the x axis labels overlapping and ranging from -250 to 5250. Having the second argument there eliminates this overlapping and shows the categories in which the data falls in, which gives the graph above. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: That answers the first of the 3 questions I asked.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I went ahead and edited the original post - hopefully this is much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first say, that you define the range of the x-axis by the first array in `plt.xticks` (i.e. your variable `x_axis`) which runs from -250, and then you kind of glue different values on top of that (by your list of strings), probably in order to fix what does not do right in your eyes. While this is the purpose of `xticks` (e.g. showing weekdays while under the hood still act as numbers from 0 to 6), your way is a misuse: I would not see clear either if I were you.
However, IMHO you simply want a histogram, don't you?

Let's check that:

```
plt.figure()
values = [2240, 1990, 1460, 1600, 1440, 2240, 100, 5840]
bins = np.arange(0,6001,500)
plt.hist(values, bins, rwidth=.9)
plt.xticks(bins)
```

will plot:

[image]